# Cisco ISE 1.2.5 - Exporting Custom Reports

Tags: cisco, export, reporting

Having some troubles exporting reports from ISE when they have a custom time period. Trying to export the past 5 months, but even a custom period of the last 4 days for example will not export.

I can view the report in the browser, but when I go to export to a repo, it never gets there. Pre-configured reports end up on the repo just fine.

In particular, it's the Registered Endpoints report I'm having trouble with.

And yes, I am performing the export from the Primary PAP.

Any suggestions? Anybody had anything similar?

Comment: Have raised as a TAC case. Will advise of the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed [as bug CSCul08673](https://tools.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCul08673) in ISE 1.2 by Cisco.

TAC engineer has confirmed it is still present in patch 7, and is possible it will be fixed in 1.2.1 code.

Workaround is "Use pre-configured time ranges". Which doesn't help me, because the reason I wanted the custom reports is because you can't go back far enough in the pre-configured time ranges.

Will report if I come up with a better workaround.

Sorry I don't have a better answer.